# Stitching of Coset Diagrams

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Can any one assist me to give me concept of Handles in the coset diagram? How do we identify it and how can we make new presentaions by joining the handles of the coset diagrams of distinct groups? Any material relating to the composition of the coset diagrams?

Comment: Any material which I fnd useful that how do we treat composing the coset diagrams

Comment: I am not aware of such functionality existing in GAP. Could you point to a reference for the definition of handles, please?

Comment: @ Alexander joining handles of coset diagrams of certain index of subgroup of a group is the concept behind stiching of coset diagrams. I have given the definition of handle of coset diagram in the answer of this question. Stiching means if Coset diagram D1 has handle (a,b) and D2 has handle (c,d) then joining these coset diagrams such that (a,c) and (b,d). the resultant coset diagram with have the same properties of the group but has degree m+n where m is the degree of coset diagram on D1 and n is the degree of coset diagram D2. this is known as stiching of the coset diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concept of Handles in Coset Diagram was first intoduced by W.W.Stothers. 
For instanc if we making a coset diagram of subgroup of index 14 of extended triangle group trianglegroup $ (2,3,7)=<x,y,t;x^2,y^3,t^2,(xt)^2,(yt)^2,(xy)^7> $ where x is represented by Edges y by triangle (3-gon) permuted anticlockwise and t is the reflection along the vertical axis of symmetry.

Those points in the coset diagram which are fixed by x that are represented by heavy dot and permuted in t i.e parallel to the axis of symmetry, such pairs in the coset diagram are called handle in teh coset diagrams.

Comment: thanks - could you also add some references to papers, please?

Comment: Subgroups of the (2,3,7) Triangle Group by W.W Stothers in Manuscripta mathematica. 20, 323-334 (1977) by Springer Verlag